# Check the difference between string i and p

Tags: python

How would I go about checking to see what the difference between string p and i? So the 2nd line can equal the first line.

```
t=int(input())
print(t)
for i in range(t):
    print(i)
    i=input()
    p=input()
    print(i,p)
    print('Case #'+(str(i+1))+': ')
    if len(i)==0:
        #print(len(p))
    else:
        #print((len(p)-len(i)))
```

Help Barbara find out how many extra letters she needs to remove in order to obtain I or if I cannot be obtained from P by removing letters then output IMPOSSIBLE.

input:

```
2
aaaa
aaaaa
bbbbb
bbbbc
```

output:

```
Case #1: 1
Case #2: IMPOSSIBLE
```

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a place to share homework questions. You should format your question to be a minimal reproducible example of your problem, and to be generalised, so that answers will help others. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Levenshtein distance` to calculate the difference and decide what is possible and impossible yourself.

You can find more resources on YouTube to understand the concept better. E.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=We3YDTzNXEk

I have provided a version of code for your convenient as well.

```
import numpy as np

def calculate_edit_distance(source, target):
    '''Calculate the edit distance from source to target
    [In] source="ab" target="bc"
    [Out] return 2
    '''
    num_row = len(target) + 1
    num_col = len(source) + 1
    distance_table = np.array([[0] * num_col for _ in range(num_row)])

    # getting from X[0...i] to empty target string requires i deletions
    distance_table[:, 0] = [i for i in range(num_row)]

    # getting from Y[0...i] to empty source string requires i deletions
    distance_table[0] = [i for i in range(num_col)]

    # loop through all the characters and calculate their respective distances
    for i in range(num_row - 1):
        for j in range(num_col - 1):
            insert = distance_table[i + 1, j]
            delete = distance_table[i, j + 1]
            substitute = distance_table[i, j]

            # if target char and source char are the same,
            # just copy the diagonal value
            if target[i] == source[j]:
                distance_table[i + 1, j + 1] = substitute
            else:
                operations = [delete, insert, substitute]
                best_operation = np.argmin(operations)

                if best_operation == 2:  # +2 if the operation is to substitute
                    distance_table[i + 1, j + 1] = substitute + 2
                else:  # same formula for both delete and insert operation
                    distance_table[i + 1, j + 1] = operations[best_operation] + 1

    return distance_table[num_row - 1, num_col - 1]
```